# ERROR Failed to start Neo Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, neo4j

I have to use neo4j for my rails application.
So I started installing the neo4j server.I followed steps to install [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-installation.html) on linux.

But when I run

```
./bin/neo4j console
```

It gives

```
ERROR Failed to start Neo Server on port [unknown port] Bad value 'conf/neo4j-http-logging.xml' for setting 'org.neo4j.server.http.log.config': HTTP log directory [/opt/neo4j-community-2.3.2/data/log] is not writeable.

org.neo4j.graphdb.config.InvalidSettingException: Bad value 'conf/neo4j-http-logging.xml' for setting 'org.neo4j.server.http.log.config': HTTP log directory [/opt/neo4j-community-2.3.2/data/log] is not writeable.
```

I am unable to start the neo4j server.Help me how to resolve it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The error message very clearly mentions the root cause:

> HTTP log directory [/opt/neo4j-community-2.3.2/data/log] is not writeable.

So check file permissions and fix them so the user running neo4j can write to that directory.